# ios style folder animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, html, css

I am currently working on a video thumbnail gallery that has two rows of 5 images for a total of 10 images. The functionality is the user clicks on the video thumb and a ios folder like animation happens and within the opened area is the video with some info. I currently have half of it working but I am having a hard time figuring out the functionality for the bottom row. I would like when a user clicks on the second row of video thumbs the area opens up above the video. Here is a link to what I have so far [http://jsfiddle.net/jsavage/Vnya7/14/]  hopefully it will make more sense as to what I am trying to do. Any help would be greatly appreciate!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a rough idea how can you achieve such effect. 
I have put updated your Fiddle here:http://jsfiddle.net/Vnya7/29/

For understanding, I have created function with multiple argument for visibility.

`function expandToDirection(self, row, content, dir) {..}`

Basically with the right class assigment you will know which row is calling like I the following `<div class="row bottom">`. Note the bottom is another argument to a direction.

With this direction, I could easily inject the element needed before/after:

```
if (dir == direction.top) {
    row.before(content);  // will inject content before the said row
    content.find(".folderName").text($(self).text());

} else if (dir == direction.bottom) {
    row.after(content);   // will inject content after the said row
    content.find(".folderName").text($(self).text());

}
```

Once the injection is done, you could simply add to the `.folderContent` any styling class to offset the position so it appears align. Other than that, it is a matter of trial and error.

#### jQuery Documentation

> **.before( content [, content ] )**
>   Description: Insert content, specified by the parameter, before each element in the set of matched elements.
>   See: http://api.jquery.com/after/
>
> **.after( content [, content ] )**
>   Description: Insert content, specified by the parameter, after each element in the set of matched elements.
>   See: http://api.jquery.com/before/

Comment: Ikmal thank you very much for the help and for explaining this. I have been stuck trying to figure this out and I truly appreciate the help. A million thanks!!